# Create background process in Heroku without using worker

Tags: python, heroku, worker

My web application will need to execute 1 specific function every 1 hour. Does it have anyway to deploy it into Heroku without using worker (I'm using Python)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Heroku scheduler addon](https://addons.heroku.com/marketplace/scheduler) to trigger your function every hour, it's free and it doesn't require a dedicated worker.

You just need to make sure it's callable from a single file (i.e. `python do_something.py`)